# Suspended user can change display name by copying it from another site

Tags: bug, display-names, account-suspension, profile-sync, network-wide-suspension

I'll start from the bug result:

> [image: Suspended user who now has a new name: „Community“]

Having the name "Community", with 1 rep, is causing confusion when the user has lots of content and activity on the site, especially for new users. Also, the user could easily choose some offensive name.

This happened as result of the user changing their name on a site **where not suspended** and choosing "Copy to All Sites", and the change propagated to the site(s) where they are suspended.

Can the name change please be blocked on the sites where the user is currently suspended?

Comment: Suspended user also can change description. Should we block description changing too?

Comment: @Suvitruf you got proof for that? If so then yes of course, they shouldn't be allowed to change anything.

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. I've never been suspended (:

Comment: Meanwhile, the fact that they seem to have a 1x1 pixel profile image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAE4u.gif?s=328&g=1) is also shady...

Comment: @Laurel nah, it's like this for years, and can't see any problem with that. Pretty sure I saw other users with such "avatar", who are legit and fine users. (Who simply don't want to have any avatar at all.)

Comment: Update: the user now has the username "Guest".

Comment: @Sonic yeah, looks like that person is playing/trolling with us.

Comment: So tempted to edit their recent names into the "changing username on a whim" answer to the meme post...

Comment: @Sonic since it's part of non-legit actions, and at least one name was offensive in the past, I prefer it will stay out of that meme post.

Comment: I'm just joking :)

Comment: I feel slightly guilty now...